# SP's JavaScript function to create pagination

Tags: 2013, javascript, paging

SharePoint 2013 here.
I need to create a pagination of results I get from an external web service.
I want to use the look and feel of SharePoints pagination:

[image: SharePoint paginator]

Ideally I could call SharePoint's JavaScript function to create the pagination passing on needed parameters, i.e. max number of pages, index of current page.

The return value I'd then modify in terms of behaviour to call my pagination methods (additional web service calls).

Anyone an idea how to "borrow" this function to create the pagination from SharePoint?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The rendering of list and pagination is based on a `list context` and AFAIU you don't have it. You could take part of the `core.js`  or `clientetemplates.js` functions and rewrite it....but it woud be a struggly job...